# java.io in debian

Tags: java, compilation, javacc, java-io

i try to compile a java program but in the import section of the code fails:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
//import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.awt.image.renderable.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
//import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
//import javax.media.jai.*;
//import javax.media.jai.operator.*;
//import com.sun.media.jai.codec.*;
//import java.lang.reflect.*;
```

how can i fix the problem in a linux debian machine?. Thanks

```
Java Compiler Compiler Version 4.1d1 (Parser Generator) 
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help) 
Reading from file SAVE.JSigpac.java . . . 
org.javacc.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "import" "import "" at line 443, column 1. Was expecting: "PARSER_BEGIN" ... 
Detected 1 errors and 0 warnings.
```

Comment: Please describe what "fails" is supposed to mean. If it is a compilation error, what is the error, on which line? Also, use the code formatting button in the editor.

Comment: could you please post the error message !?

Comment: It's not a debian issue ;) Probably one of those Non-JRE-Classes are missing, but we can't helkp you solve the problem when you don't tell us the error message.

Comment: Also, which JDK are you using (Sun's, OpenJDK, something else)?

Comment: We don't read minds here, you know.

Comment: Java Compiler Compiler Version 4.1d1 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file SAVE.JSigpac.java . . .
org.javacc.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "import" "import "" at line 443, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "PARSER_BEGIN" ...
    
Detected 1 errors and 0 warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**javacc** is not for compiling java source files, use **javac**!

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, i installed jdk and i fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JavaCC is a framework if you want to build your own compiler and runtime for a language. Not for your compiling java-files.

Answer (score 0):

Being more specific, you're incorrectly using [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC), when what you probably want to use is [javac](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html).  Give the latter a try and report back?  If you don't have javac, you'll need to install an SDK (not just the JRE!)

Comment: If he has javacc, he'll have javac too ;)